# Animation from 0 to 1 opacity does not work in FireFox but works in Chrome

Tags: css, css-animations

I have following code for html and CSS to apply animation so that the logo image fades from  opacity of 0 to 1. This works very well in latest Chrome browser, but not in latest FireFox or IE 11.

I have made sure that initial opacity of the logo image is 0 through 'logo-new' class, so when animation happens it starts from 0 opacity.

**Question**: How can I make this type of animation work in FireFox and IE 11?

HTML

```
<div id="newlogo" class="logo-new animate"></div>
```

CSS

```
.logo-new {
    background-image: url("../logo.png");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    height: 95px;
    opacity: 0;
    width: 479px;
}


.animate {
    -moz-animation: fadeIn 1s ease-in;
    -webkit-animation: fadeIn 1s ease-in;
    animation: fadeIn ease-in 1s 1;
    -moz-animation-delay: 1s;
    -webkit-animation-delay: 1s;
    animation-delay: 1s;
    -moz-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

@-webkit-keyframes fadeIn {
    from {opacity: 0;}
    to {opacity: 1;}
}


@keyframes fadeOut {
    from {opacity: 1;}
    to {opacity: .5;}
}
```

**UPDATE 1**

As mentioned in comments by 'uʍopǝpısdn', that I needed to include keyframes for mozilla for it to work in FireFox. However, very surprisingly, for IE 11 I had to include a keyframes element without any browser prefix, and it didn't have to be at the top of the CSS.

```
.logo-new {
    background-image: url("../logo.png");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    height: 95px;
    opacity: 0;
    width: 479px;
}


.animate {
    -moz-animation: fadeIn 1s ease-in;
    -o-animation: fadeIn 1s ease-in;
    -webkit-animation: fadeIn 1s ease-in;
    animation: fadeIn ease-in 1s 1;
    -moz-animation-delay: 1s;
    -o-animation-delay: 1s;
    -webkit-animation-delay: 1s;
    animation-delay: 1s;
    -moz-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    -o-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

//IE 11 Fix for animation. Exclude browser prefix !!!!!
@keyframes fadeIn {
    from {opacity: 0;}
    to {opacity: 1;}
}

@-webkit-keyframes fadeIn {
    from {opacity: 0;}
    to {opacity: 1;}
}

//Fix for animation to work in FireFox. Include a 'moz' prefix
@-moz-keyframes fadeIn {
    from {opacity: 0;}
    to {opacity: 1;}
}
```

Comment: You need to include a @-moz-keyframes version for FF

Comment: Ok. Great. Let me check that.

Comment: That works for FireFox, but not for IE 11.

Comment: Also, can you please post this as an answer?

Comment: It wouldn't be a good answer as it doesn't solve your IE11 issue.

Comment: Try moving the `@keyframes` to the top of the css document, thats work on IE 10 and IE 11.

Comment: What worked for IE 11 was including keyframes fadeIn class that hs no prefix.

Comment: You already had a non-prefixed version in your original code

Comment: @uʍopǝpısdn, Not for fadeIn. The animation was using fadeIn and not fadeOut.

Comment: @uʍopǝpısdn Firefox has supported unprefixed keyframes for nearly three years. Unless OP is using Firefox version 15 or older, I don't think that will be useful.

Comment: @TylerH read the comment thread.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following CSS worked.

- For FireFox include a 'moz' prefixed keyframes element in your CSS.
- For IE 11 include an non-prefixed keyframes element in your CSS at any position and not necessarily at the top of the CSS.

  ```
  .logo-new {
  background-image: url("../logo.png");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  height: 95px;
  opacity: 0;
  width: 479px;
  }


  .animate {
  -moz-animation: fadeIn 1s ease-in;
  -webkit-animation: fadeIn 1s ease-in;
  animation: fadeIn ease-in 1s 1;
  -moz-animation-delay: 1s;
  -webkit-animation-delay: 1s;
  animation-delay: 1s;
  -moz-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  }

   //IE 11 Fix for animation. Exclude browser prefix
   @keyframes fadeIn {
  from {opacity: 0;}
  to {opacity: 1;}
  }

  @-webkit-keyframes fadeIn {
     from {opacity: 0;}
     to {opacity: 1;}
  }

  //FireFox fix for animation. Inlcude 'moz' prefixed keyframes element
  @-moz-keyframes fadeIn {
  from {opacity: 0;}
  to {opacity: 1;}
  }
  ```

**UPDATE**

Even though the above CSS makes the animation work in IE 11 and FireFox, I found that we really don't need any 'moz' prefixed styles if using FireFox 38.x or any 'ms' prefixed styles for IE 11.

This means that IE 11 and FireFox 38.x do not need any browser specific styles for animation, which is a better solution in my view.  But Google Chrome 42.x is an exception and does need 'webkit' prefixed styles for animation.  So we can do away with all styles that are prefixed by 'moz' or 'ms' in above CSS and still have it work in IE 11 and FireFox 38.x.

Comment: The `-o-` prefix is for Opera, not IE. IE prefixes are usually `-ms-`, though like you said, IE has never used a prefixed version of keyframe animations since the day it was first supported in that browser.

Comment: @TylerH, Sorry my mistake. Changed my UPDATE to reflect this. Thanks.